# date time change in onlocation changed

Tags: android, web-services, datetime, locationlistener

Ive created an android app which posts to Web Services. This is supposed to check the users location and provide relative information to that gps update in terms of their position and the date time. The rest of the functions work fine but the date time always remains the same and i have no idea why. Some insight would prove helpful.

Here is some of my code.

LocationListener

```
    String lati, longi, alti, timeStamp;
    float speed;
    int counter = 0;
     Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Location", "Hello World");
        lati = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longi = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        alti = String.valueOf(location.getAltitude());
        speed = location.getSpeed();            
        timeStamp = dateFormat.format(date);
        counter++;

        RequestInfo requestInfo = new RequestInfo(sessionID, lati, longi, alti, speed, timeStamp);
        database.addRequest(requestInfo);

        textView.setText("" + counter);

    }
```

The requestInfo is a class which sets up the request for the web service. This is a constructor that provides all the info needed for a web service

Answer (score 0):

You create the instance *date* only once, when the object containing *date* is created. Therefore its value stays unchanged. Instead, move it inside your `onLocationChanged` method. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ...
    Date date = new Date();
    timeStamp = dateFormat.format(date);
    ...
}
```

Or you can use [Calendar class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and its methods like [getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) as in [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_gettime.htm)

Comment: Thanks man, I wasnt sure if the date would just automatically update itself or i had to recreate it each time! Just checked it there and this works :)

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, you can use Calendar class as well. See the last sentence, I just updated.

Comment: Yeah I had a look into the Calendar class as I wasn't sure if Date implemented the time feature. Date was slightly less code so I went for that just out of laziness!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same date object to get the date and time instance. 
Use new Date object every time. This works for me.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ....        
    timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    ....

}
```